# How to use the sign in password in vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I have VBA code in my Outlook . The code fires ONLY if i am signed in on Outlook . I use my Outlook password as one of the variables . So far i am hard coding my password as `pwd = "xxx"`

```
...
Dim pwd as String
pwd = "xxx"
.....
```

---

However since this script fires from outlook i think that there is a way to get the current password without hardcoding it . How can i do this

```
 ...
Dim pwd as String
pwd = 'getCurrentOutlookPassword !
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read the domain credentials. There might be a way to read POP3/SMYP/IMAP4 credentials. What is the password used for?

Comment: to connect to database . i have the same pwd for my outlook and database

Comment: What Outlook password do you mean? PST password? POP3/SMTP password? Domain password for the primary Exchange mailbox?

Comment: You can read Redemption and its RDOPOP3Account to read the password: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm#RDOPOP3Account